# Parse string of key=values with escaped characters

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, fluentd, observability

Loki outputs the following log in a key-value format with the structure `key1=value1 key2=value2`:

```
level=info ts=2023-10-20T14:30:48.716410806Z caller=metrics.go:159 component=frontend org_id=fake traceID=58290ebda8d79180 latency=fast query=\"sum by (level) (count_over_time({k8s_namespace=\\\"ingress-nginx\\\"} |= ``[1s]))\" query_hash=110010092 query_type=metric range_type=range length=15m0.001s start_delta=15m0.833402507s end_delta=832.40267ms step=1s duration=61.999532ms status=200 limit=1000 returned_lines=0 throughput=4.2MB total_bytes=260kB total_bytes_structured_metadata=0B lines_per_second=4209 total_lines=261 post_filter_lines=261 total_entries=1 store_chunks_download_time=0s queue_time=819.962996ms splits=2 shards=32 cache_chunk_req=0 cache_chunk_hit=0 cache_chunk_bytes_stored=0 cache_chunk_bytes_fetched=0 cache_chunk_download_time=0s cache_index_req=0 cache_index_hit=0 cache_index_download_time=0s cache_stats_results_req=0 cache_stats_results_hit=0 cache_stats_results_download_time=0s cache_result_req=0 cache_result_hit=0 cache_result_download_time=0s source=logvolhist
```

In fluentd, I'm trying to parse this log using the [Labeled Tab-separated Values](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/ltsv) parser, with `delimiter_pattern` as `/\s+/` and `label_delimiter` as `=` and get the following result:

```json
{
  "level": "info",
  "caller": "metrics.go:159",
  "component": "frontend",
  "org_id": "fake",
  "traceID": "58290ebda8d79180",
  "latency": "fast",
  "query": "\"sum",
  "(count_over_time({k8s_namespace": "\\\"ingress-nginx\\\"}",
  "|": "",
  "query_hash": "110010092",
  "query_type": "metric",
  "range_type": "range",
  ...
}
```

For the key `query` this parser can only capture the first word and uses the space that comes after as a delimiter for another key-value.

I've tried different [RegEx expressions](https://github.com/GEBITSolutions/fluent-plugin-fortigate-logs-parser/blob/9f5e3c31e762d5839e0f446054f9347da1892879/lib/fluent/plugin/parser_fortigate_logs.rb#L5), and two plugin parsers (https://shihadeh.dev/ruby-gems/Key-ValueParser/ & https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-kv-parser) but no luck so far.

Is it a matter of getting the right regex, using a different parser, trying to unescape the characters or something else?

Comment: I don't know Fluentd, but does [`(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>[^"\s]+(?!\S)|\\"(?:[^\\"]|\\{3}")*\\")`](https://regex101.com/r/fW0LiL/1) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer. Note that this assumes every `\"` in your example is a sequence of two characters and not one escaped double quote.

Comment: If you're just trying to match the delimiters: `\s(?=\w+=(\\")?.+?(?(1)\1(?=\s)))`

Comment: isn't this just JSON? Why do you need regex

Comment: @Mark The output is JSON. The input is a single-line list of key/value pairs separated by spaces.

Comment: @InSync It would be nice, but to use the [regex parser](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/regexp) in fluentd, I need to define named capture groups. I think that the example you provided would output {"key":"level", "value":"info"}.

Comment: @CAustin wow thank you, this almost does it! Now i'm getting `"query": "\"sum by (level) (count_over_time({k8s_namespace=\\\"loki\\\","` from this example `query=\"sum by (level) (count_over_time({k8s_namespace=\\\"loki\\\", k8s_component=\\\"backend\\\"} |= ``[1s]))\"` 
I think you can write an answer to the post with this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\s(?=\w+=(\\")?.+?(?(1)\1(?=\s)))
```

From the comment by @CAustin, this regex for the `delimiter_pattern` works better than just `/\s+/`

### Extra

This is for my specific case regarding Fluentd and log parsing. In the meantime, after analysing Fluentd and Fluent bit better, I'll probably switch to using Fluent bit because of the parsing capabilities.

To whom it may concern :p